# What is the best way to work with xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

what is the best way to work with xml file that represets a tree.
the xml size is 70mb.

Comment: if your xml file is of 70mb, I think You should manage the data into different small xml files.

Comment: @ZainShaikh: Nonsense. We regularly consume XML files of many gigabytes. Many suppliers publish their data as XML.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you want to do with the XML. Generally with files that size you wouldn't want to read it all in one go. As such the following page makes an interesting read, providing a means to mine data from the file without loading it in memory. It allows you to combine the speed of XmlReader with the flexibility of Linq:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387035.aspx

And quite an interesting article based on this technique:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xmlteam/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2)

Comment: Great link, unless you work with xml a lot, keeping up with the technology can be challenging. thanks for linking these articles!

Answer (score 2):

Linq to XML is the easiest way to currently work with xml but this will typically load the entrire tree into memory which in your case with a 70mb file may not be ideal.
However there are ways around this as demonstrated in [this blog post from Mick Taulty.](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/09/08/9803.aspx)

Comment: Mick's technique (the same technique as I linked to in my answer) is particularly well suited to huge XML files. I've have to deal with DB dumps in files that are 2-3GB in size and this technique makes it much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data from a large xml file `XmlTextReader` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 3.5 and up, I prefer using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx?ppud=4) for all my work towards XML files.

Answer (score 0):

LinqToXml is probably a good bet if you wish to query it in memory, but if you find that you are getting problems with how large your memory footprint is you could use an XMLReader

### Linq To XML

- Slower for larger documents (large memory footprint)
- Queryable

### XmlTextReader

- Fast
- Only one line at a time, so no querying

Comment: I want to find some indexing solution for this problem. It is very slow to find something at the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a DOM, an alternative XML parser you could try is a SAX parser.  Instead of loading the entire tree into memory, a SAX parser is event-driven and handles nodes, etc. as it encounters them.

Further Reading: http://www.saxproject.org/event.html